# Reading a gzipfile in R console

Tags: r

I am trying to read a gzip file but I can't get it to open. What am I doing wrong? These are the errors I am getting. If I put the file in the wrong place where do I have to place it to get it to recognize it?

> read.fasta(unz(H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz))
> Error in read.fasta(unz(H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz)) :
> could not find function "read.fasta"
> myData <- read.table('H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz')
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open file 'H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz': No such file or directory
>
> myData <- read.table('H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz')
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open file 'H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: the error message informs us R could not find function `read.fasta`
Perhaps try `fread` from the `data.table` package. Also, since you are not specifying file path. Use `getwd()` to find working directory and make sure your `gz` file is in this directory

Comment: Can r read a gzip file?

Comment: Absolutely. Load up `data.table` using `library(data.table)` then use `fread(H_sapiens_RefSeq.fasta.gz)`. But like I said, if ur not specifying file path make sure your `gz` file is in working directory